# Analyze a control table by Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut

A shell script is analysing a control table to get the right parameter for it's processing.
Currently, it is simple - using grep, it points to the correct line, awk {print $n} determines the right columns.
Columns are separated by space only. No special rules, just values separated by space.
All is fine and working, the users like it.
As long as none of the columns is left empty. For last colum, it's ok to leave it empty, but if somebody does not fill  in a column in the mid, it confuses the awk {print $n} logic.
Of course, one could as the users to fill in every entry, or one could just define the column delimiter as ";" . 
In case something is skipped, one could use   " ;; " However, I would prefer not to change table style.
So the question is:
How to effectively analyze a table having blanks in colum values? Table is like this:

> ```
> ApplikationService    ServerName    PortNumber     ControlValue_1    ControlValue_2    
> Read                  chavez.com       3599         john                 doe    
> Write                                  3345         johnny               walker    
> Update                curiosity.org                 jerry
> ```

What might be of some help: 
If there is a value set in a column, it is (more a less precise) under its column header description.

Cheers,
Tarik

Comment: In my mind, a potential solution is to determine the columns by their respective header line. If column header for port number is e.g from column 30 to 40, the script looks in columns 30 to 40 to get a port number. Something in: OK, used as port number. Nothing found / Empty: Skipped.
But I'm afraid the effort, considering my Shell skills :-)   
A potential side effekt is of course, header must always consume same or more space/rows than value, but this can be managed.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the input data? Is it possible that values may exceed the column defined by the header, writing into the next column? Can values have spaces too? Are the possible values for each column determinable (e.g. always `[0-9]` for the "PortNumber" column, a known set of strings for the "ControlValue_1/2" column). Please update your question. I'd also suggest to update the title to reflect your requirements like "Parse space separated values with values missing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what your desired output is but this shows you the right approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    print
    while ( match($0,/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/) ) {
        width[++i] = RLENGTH
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    next
}
{
    i = 0
    while ( (fld = substr($0,1,width[++i])) != "" ) {
        gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",fld)
        printf "%-*s", width[i], (fld == "" ? "[empty]" : fld)
        $0 = substr($0,width[i]+1)
    }
    print ""
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ApplikationService    ServerName    PortNumber     ControlValue_1    ControlValue_2
Read                  chavez.com    3599           john              doe
Write                 [empty]       3345           johnny            walker
Update                curiosity.org [empty]        jerry             [empty]
```

It uses the width of the each field in the title line to determine the width of every field in every line of the file, and then just replaces empty fields with the string "[empty]" and left-aligns every field just to pretty it up a bit.

Comment: Ed, Thanks a lot! It is what I had in mind and it will do for sure! :-))